# How do I use 2 propertyChange methods in 1 class?

Tags: java, swing, javabeans

so I have a program that has 3 elements: a reusable StepPanel that increases or decreases the size of the figure, a reusable JavaBean InitialField that shows the current size, and a Picture class that extends Canvas and holds a Rectangle and a Circle. Here's how it looks:

[image]

Currently both stepPanels update (increase/decrease) size of both the Circle and Square, since my propertyChange method sets both of them together. What I want to do is make stepPanel1 increase the Square and stepPanel2 increase the Circle. I can't seem to think of anything except making a 2nd propertyChange method, however you can't do that in the same class, and I must do it with 1 class only. Here's my Picture Canvas class:

```
import java.awt.Canvas;
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.beans.PropertyChangeEvent;
import java.beans.PropertyChangeListener;
import java.beans.PropertyVetoException;
import java.beans.VetoableChangeListener;

public class Picture extends Canvas implements VetoableChangeListener, PropertyChangeListener {
    private final int SIZE = 100;
    private int radius = 1;
    private int side = 1;

    public Picture() {
        setSize(SIZE,SIZE);
    }

    @Override
    public void vetoableChange(PropertyChangeEvent pce) throws PropertyVetoException {
        if ((pce.getPropertyName()).equals("value")) {
            int v = (Integer)pce.getNewValue();
            if ((v <=0)||(v > SIZE/2))
                throw new PropertyVetoException ("Value out of bounds!", pce);        
        }   
    }


    @Override
    public void propertyChange(PropertyChangeEvent pce) {
        if ((pce.getPropertyName()).equals("value")) {
            setRadius((Integer)pce.getNewValue());
            setSide((Integer)pce.getNewValue());
            repaint();
        }
    }

    public void setRadius(int radius) {
        this.radius = radius;
    }

    public int getRadius() {
        return this.radius;
    }

    public void setSide(int side) {
        this.side = side;
    }

    public int getSide() {
        return this.side;
    }

    @Override
    public void paint (Graphics g) {
        Dimension d = getSize();
        g.setColor(Color.GREEN);
        g.fillOval(d.width/2 - radius, d.height/2 - radius, radius*2, radius*2);
        g.setColor(Color.BLUE);
        g.drawRect(d.width/2 - side, d.height/2 - side, side*2, side*2);
    }

}
```

Here is my StepPanel class:

```
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;

public class StepPanel extends javax.swing.JPanel implements ActionListener {

    private int step = 0;

    public StepPanel() {
        initComponents();
        btnUp.addActionListener(this);
        btnDown.addActionListener(this);
    }

    /**
     * This method is called from within the constructor to initialize the form.
     * WARNING: Do NOT modify this code. The content of this method is always
     * regenerated by the Form Editor.
     */
    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    // <editor-fold defaultstate="collapsed" desc="Generated Code">                          
    private void initComponents() {

        btnDown = new javax.swing.JButton();
        btnUp = new javax.swing.JButton();

        btnDown.setText("<<");

        btnUp.setText(">>");

        javax.swing.GroupLayout layout = new javax.swing.GroupLayout(this);
        this.setLayout(layout);
        layout.setHorizontalGroup(
            layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
            .addGroup(layout.createSequentialGroup()
                .addGap(2, 2, 2)
                .addComponent(btnDown)
                .addPreferredGap(javax.swing.LayoutStyle.ComponentPlacement.RELATED)
                .addComponent(btnUp)
                .addContainerGap())
        );
        layout.setVerticalGroup(
            layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
            .addGroup(layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.BASELINE)
                .addComponent(btnUp)
                .addComponent(btnDown))
        );
    }// </editor-fold>                        

    public void setStep(int step){
        int oldStep = this.step;
        this.step = step;
        firePropertyChange("step", oldStep, this.step);
        this.step = 0;
    }

    public int getStep() {
        return this.step;
    }

    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
        if ((e.getSource()).equals(btnUp)) 
            setStep(1); 
        if ((e.getSource()).equals(btnDown))
            setStep(-1);
    }

    // Variables declaration - do not modify                     
    private javax.swing.JButton btnDown;
    private javax.swing.JButton btnUp;
    // End of variables declaration                   
}
```

Here's InitialField:

```
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.beans.PropertyChangeEvent;
import java.beans.PropertyChangeListener;
import java.beans.PropertyVetoException;
import javax.swing.JTextField;


public class InitialField extends JTextField  implements ActionListener,
                                                         PropertyChangeListener{
    private int value;

    /** Creates a new instance of InitialField */
    public InitialField() {
        addActionListener(this);
    }

    public void setValue (int value) {
        try {
            int oldValue = this.value;
            fireVetoableChange("value", oldValue, value); // Generates PropertyeChangeEvent
            this.value = value;
            firePropertyChange("value", oldValue, value); // Generates PropertyChangeEvent
        }
        catch (PropertyVetoException pve) {
            pve.printStackTrace();
        }
        setText(getValue() + "");
    }

    public int getValue () {
        return this.value;
    }

    // <Enter>
    public void actionPerformed (ActionEvent e) { 
         try {
             setValue(Integer.parseInt(getText())); // setValue()
         }
        catch (NumberFormatException ex) {
            ex.printStackTrace();                
        }           
    }

    public void propertyChange(PropertyChangeEvent pce) {
        if (pce.getPropertyName().equals("step"))
            setValue(getValue() + (Integer) pce.getNewValue());
    }
}
```

And last, here's the Form:

```
public class Form extends javax.swing.JFrame {

    /**
     * Creates new form Form
     */
    public Form() {
        initComponents();
        initialField1.addVetoableChangeListener(picture1);
        initialField1.addPropertyChangeListener(picture1);
        initialField2.addVetoableChangeListener(picture1);
        initialField2.addPropertyChangeListener(picture1);
        stepPanel1.addPropertyChangeListener(initialField1);
        stepPanel2.addPropertyChangeListener(initialField2);
    }

    /**
     * This method is called from within the constructor to initialize the form.
     * WARNING: Do NOT modify this code. The content of this method is always
     * regenerated by the Form Editor.
     */
    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    // <editor-fold defaultstate="collapsed" desc="Generated Code">                          
    private void initComponents() {

        stepPanel1 = new test.StepPanel();
        initialField1 = new test.InitialField();
        picture1 = new test.Picture();
        stepPanel2 = new test.StepPanel();
        initialField2 = new test.InitialField();

        setDefaultCloseOperation(javax.swing.WindowConstants.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

        initialField1.setText("0");

        initialField2.setText("0");

        javax.swing.GroupLayout layout = new javax.swing.GroupLayout(getContentPane());
        getContentPane().setLayout(layout);
        layout.setHorizontalGroup(
            layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
            .addGroup(layout.createSequentialGroup()
                .addContainerGap(javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, Short.MAX_VALUE)
                .addGroup(layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
                    .addGroup(layout.createSequentialGroup()
                        .addGroup(layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
                            .addComponent(stepPanel1, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                            .addComponent(initialField1, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 104, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE))
                        .addGap(37, 37, 37)
                        .addComponent(picture1, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE))
                    .addComponent(stepPanel2, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                    .addComponent(initialField2, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 103, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)))
        );
        layout.setVerticalGroup(
            layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
            .addGroup(layout.createSequentialGroup()
                .addGroup(layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
                    .addGroup(layout.createSequentialGroup()
                        .addGap(46, 46, 46)
                        .addComponent(initialField1, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                        .addPreferredGap(javax.swing.LayoutStyle.ComponentPlacement.UNRELATED)
                        .addComponent(stepPanel1, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE))
                    .addGroup(layout.createSequentialGroup()
                        .addContainerGap()
                        .addComponent(picture1, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)))
                .addGap(18, 18, 18)
                .addComponent(initialField2, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                .addPreferredGap(javax.swing.LayoutStyle.ComponentPlacement.RELATED)
                .addComponent(stepPanel2, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE))
        );

        pack();
    }// </editor-fold>                        

    /**
     * @param args the command line arguments
     */
    public static void main(String args[]) {
        /* Set the Nimbus look and feel */
        //<editor-fold defaultstate="collapsed" desc=" Look and feel setting code (optional) ">
        /* If Nimbus (introduced in Java SE 6) is not available, stay with the default look and feel.
         * For details see http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/lookandfeel/plaf.html 
         */
        try {
            for (javax.swing.UIManager.LookAndFeelInfo info : javax.swing.UIManager.getInstalledLookAndFeels()) {
                if ("Nimbus".equals(info.getName())) {
                    javax.swing.UIManager.setLookAndFeel(info.getClassName());
                    break;
                }
            }
        } catch (ClassNotFoundException ex) {
            java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(Form.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        } catch (InstantiationException ex) {
            java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(Form.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        } catch (IllegalAccessException ex) {
            java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(Form.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        } catch (javax.swing.UnsupportedLookAndFeelException ex) {
            java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(Form.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        }
        //</editor-fold>

        /* Create and display the form */
        java.awt.EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                new Form().setVisible(true);
            }
        });
    }

    // Variables declaration - do not modify                     
    private test.InitialField initialField1;
    private test.InitialField initialField2;
    private test.Picture picture1;
    private test.StepPanel stepPanel1;
    private test.StepPanel stepPanel2;
    // End of variables declaration                   
}
```

Can you please help me out and guide me on how to make stepPanel1 increase the Rectangle and stepPanel2 increase the Circle? I'll also have to make it so that the Circle doesn't become bigger than the Rectangle after that. Thank you for your help in advance!

Comment: Why do you reinvent the wheel and don't use [JSpinner](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/spinner.html)?

Comment: I see you fixed your previous problem: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49864848/how-can-i-put-2-java-swing-elements-on-top-of-each-other. Don't forget to "accept" an answer by clicking on the checkmark beside the answer. `a Picture class that extends Canvas` and you were told in that answer NOT to extend Canvas!!! Canvas is an AWT component and should not be used in a Swing application. (1-)

Comment: Hey, yeah I'll mark the other one solved and I'll pick an answer, sorry about that :). About the Canvas - I MUST use it, as stated by my teacher. Edit: I must use those 2 buttons, can't use JSpinner

Comment: `About the Canvas - I MUST use it, as stated by my teacher.` - well show your teacher the tutorial link I provided you in your last question. It shows the proper way to do custom painting. There is absolutely no reason to use a Canvas and the teacher is promoting bad habits. I suggest you switch classes and get a better teacher who will teach your to use Swing the way it was designed to be used.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> What I want to do is make stepPanel1 increase the Square and stepPanel2 increase the Circle.

Then you can have different property change events. So you might have a "side" and a "radius" event.

This is how normal Swing components work. They generate a different event for each different property that is changed.

Also, the code in your `setSide(...)` and `setRadius()` methods should be:

```
revalidate();
repaint();
```

It is the responsibility of the set???(...) method to know the property has changed and cause the component to be repainted. The repaint() should not be part of the listener code.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for the help and tips! I'll be sure to fix those things up and see how events in Swing work exactly. In the meanwhile, here's what I did to bypass this:
I created a second InitialField bean and used it for the Circle, changing the "value" to "value2". After that it's a simple addition of a second if statement in the propertyChange method. I know that's a cheesy and bad way of doing it, but for now it works. Will research on how to do it the proper way now.